# How to send an audio stream over SIP

Tags: websocket, sip, node-red

I'm developing an application that receives an audio stream over a WebSocket and needs to forward the audio to a SIP server.

Currently, I've managed to connect to the audio source using a Websocket and receive the media stream (encoded u-law) using Node-Red, but I'm struggling to figure out how to send the media stream to the SIP server. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched on https://flows.nodered.org for SIP nodes?

Comment: Thanks, @hardillb I did, there are a few nodes to make a SIP call but they only handle the initiation process, not the audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for a similar question a while back, can't find where it was now.
As you probably know the media part of SIP is RTP, so its a fairly separate stack to the call signalling.
I didn't find any nodes that supported it and the few node.js libraries for RTP were all very incomplete and out of date.
In theory it might be possible to craft your own RTP streams using the UDP nodes and then create the relevant SDP in the SIP response but I'm not sure how robust or scalable this would be.
The other option is that there are a couple of Programmable Comms platforms out there that support both SIP and Web sockets so you could possible utilise one of those and connect from Node-RED via websocket letting them do the SIP work.
I've done SIP|<>Websocket stuff with both the Vonage API (Previously Nexmo) and Jambonz (open source)